# Parse.com security : Access object of another app if you know the objectId

Tags: parse-platform, objectid

Is it possible to get data of an object/user on Parse.com, if the objectId of the ParseObject is known? I want to know about it as a security concern, if it is possible for some other app to access objects from my app if the objectId is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you have, if you're not on the ACL, you can't pull the data.  Make sure you're setting your ACLs up properly to protect your data.  Parse's docs are pretty decent in this regard:

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#security-recommendations/iOS

If you don't have any ACLs setup then everything defaults to Public Read/Write.  This means YES.  Another client would need access to your parse keys, but if they were able to find this, they would be able to access anything that isn't protected.

Comment: Hi Logan: "would need access to your parse keys, but if they were able to find this" - is there any way to get the parse keys, until someone hacks my parse account or I give it to them. Can you extract these from the .ipa or the .apk ?

Comment: Yes, it's not easy, and it's not likely, but someone could decompile your source code and access your keys.  Here's a thread with a little bit of info: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source